# jQuery hover effect

Tags: jquery, text, hover, show, effect

I'm trying to have this effect http://www.un.org/. Meaning you have different links, on hover the corresponding text appear below. Is it possible to achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with CSS alone

```
<a href="#">My Link<span>My Hover Text</span></a>

a span { display: none; }
a:hover span { display: inline; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TkVtm/

or for a more complex scenario you can use jQuery to do a simple hover effect:

```
$("#links li").hover(function() {
    $("#text li:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TkVtm/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery [Hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event and just change the div containing your corresponding text :

```
$("#hoverArea").hover(
  function () {
    $("#textDiv").text("New Text");
  },
  function () {
    $("#textDiv").text("Previous Text");
  }
);
```